# Object in 3D View not Visible in any Collection

Tags: 3d-view, collections, outliner

I have a gear object that is visible in the *3D View*, but not visible in any *collection* within the *Outliner*.

- Whenever I hide all entities inside the collection, the object is still visible.
- Whenever I hide the collection itself, everything including the object of interest hides.

The object is in a collection somewhere, I just can't find it. Can you help me find it?

[image: Project Model]
[image: Object of reference]
[image: Hidden object of reference]

Comment: select the object in viewport and then hover over the outliner and press `Numpad .` key to reveal it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gear is child of another object, so its name is hidden under this object's hierarchy. Select the gear, go to the outliner, right click and choose view > show active (or simply press dot on your numpad while hovering the outliner window).